# could my Lizardfolk exist?

Tags: science-based, biology, evolution, fantasy-races, reptiles

In a world I’m designing, a group of crocodile convergently evolved sapience becoming Lizardfolk. These are not D&D Lizardfolk, but something else. some basic characteristics of these Lizardfolk include:

- having a bird/raptor like stance
- being 5.6 feet tall
- having human level intelligence
- having baby crocodile like heads (causing them to have a weak biteforce)
- having a near bloodhound level sense of smell
- can live to be 120 years old
- having sharp claws as well as opposable thumbs
- being mesothermics
- have fast acting scar tissue and extremely strong antibodies
- have a crocodile like tail
- are good swimmers

Given these characteristics, what species of crocodile could my Lizardfolk have evolved from, and what evolutionary pressures would lead to them?

NOTE: Magic does not exist in my story

Comment: [Possible duplicate, and certainly provides the kind of information you are looking for.](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/66313/what-is-the-most-plausible-ancestor-for-tool-using-sentient-bipedal-reptilians/66371#66371)

Comment: What is a "[raptor](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/raptor)-like tail"? A tail similar to the tails of [eagles and falcons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bird_of_prey)?

Comment: @AlexP "raptor-like tail" in this case means a tail similar to that of a velociraptor

Comment: The word "raptor" means "bird of prey". It's generally considered highly recommendable to define a word before using it with an unusual meaning. (Plus there is nothing special about the tails of velociraptors. They had typical dromaeosaurid tails.) (And crocodiles are very highly specialized animals. At best, you may be looking at some descendant of basal [crocodylomorphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crocodylomorpha); but then the "lizardfolk" would not be related to crocodyles more closely than sparrows are relatex to *T. rex*.)

Comment: @AlexP i know the ideas based off how crocodiles diversified shortly after the kgb mass extinction and how crocodiles are a lot more complex compared to other lizards. having a 4 chambered heart and having basic tool use.

Comment: Crocodiles are archosaurs; lizards are lepidosaurs. Crocodiles are more closely related to dinosaurs (including birds) than they are related to lizards. (And the KGB went extinct in the 1990s, replaced by the FSB. I was not aware that crocodiles diversified so much in the last 20 years.) (Yes, I understood the reference to the K-Pg mass extinction.)

Comment: @AlexP actually yeah after the dinosaurs went extinct a variety of different animals filled the niches of them with crocodiles being an example of a group that diversified with "hoofed crocodiles" for instance. as for the lizards thing i meant to say reptile (and yes i know that birds are also reptiles).

Comment: VTC as opinion-based. We're only just beginning to understand what lead to human evolution. Expecting us to guess about what might lead to intelligent-anything-else with any sense of realism is, IMO, expecting a lot. Worse, considering that given enough time almost anything can evolve into anything... and it begs the question why you're asking? And this is *really important,* why are you asking? Your compulsion for this kind of answer will bear on the answer itself. What is your criteria for judging a best answer? If you can't explain that, then this Q is completely opinion-based.

Comment: @JBH the reason i am asking this is due to how relatively common questions asking about certain animal developing human level intelligence, and how i intend to use Lizardfolk in my story

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the most plausible ancestor for tool-using, sentient, bipedal reptilians?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/66313/what-is-the-most-plausible-ancestor-for-tool-using-sentient-bipedal-reptilians)

Comment: "have dromaeosaurid like tails" and "are good swimmers" are basically mutually exclusive, a dromaeosaurid is stiff like a pole, and would be a massive hindrance in swimming.

Comment: @John then maybe i should give them a more spinosaurus like tail.

Comment: or just a standard therapod tail, dromseosaurids are rather specialized. If you want them to be better swimmers a more crocodile like tail is perfect.

Answer (score 5):

***Poposaurus***

A bipedal predatory crocodillian from the Triassic.

[image]

[image]

***Terrestrisuchus***

is an early fast moving crocodylomorph, which was bipedal, it is small but you have an enourmous amount of time to make them whatever size you want.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Or if you want to be a little more fantastical *Canrufex* which may have been bipedal (no hind limb material exists)  which evolved after the dinosaurs were gone.

Fast moving crocodillians evolved several times and the ancestor of crocodiles may well have been warmblooded. during the time of the dinosaurs africa saw a diversification of crocodillian forms, uncluding many more active forms, so you can even make up an ancestor during this time period.

for most of these groups you have so much time you can alter them in almost any way you see fit to have your ideal ancestor.

Of course you can also just have them be an **early offshoot of dinosaurs**, before feathers evolved.

You have one BIG problem "have dromaeosaurid like tails" and "are good swimmers" are basically mutually exclusive, a dromaeosaurid is stiff like a pole, and would be a massive hindrance in swimming.

Answer (score 2):

If there were other creatures like those crocodiles to hunt the people those people might adapt to have some of these properties. It may not be exactly like "Lizarfolk" but it could come close. You also say they have human-level intelligence, can live up to 120 years, having a bird stance could have been developed prior. Then on top of these different animals and different climates might make humans want to survive and survival of the fittest might take over and all these above features(at least most of them would probably exist in the climate change or some environmental difference).

Answer (score 1):

Crocodiles aren't generally gregarious and are also semi aquatic both of which place limits on the development of tool using (no social groupings hence no pressure to develop language and fire or hunting weapons).

So I would posit an early continental drying which first forced their ancestors out of the water to become purely land based carnivores (there are fossil records of such) and perhaps a drive to social co-operation in order to protect rare watercourses/lakes etc where hatcheries were located).

The real problem however is that the 'raptor like stance' etc you want in your race  isn't going isn't going to evolve easily from crocs. (You need bird like hips for that which means a dinsourian based ancestor.) Crocs are an entirely separate branch of the animal kingdom. So...

Next you have to have a prolonged period of dry land hunting behavior which slowly favors your crocs developing those hips followed by a wetter climate and one branch of the family (perhaps smaller than others) being forced into the trees by competition. Then you just emulate human evolution.

Comment: crocodillian hips however are very close to dinosaur hips and several bipedal crocs did evolve. and they would have walked a lot like early dinosaurs. crocodiles are not an "entirely diffrent branch" more like very close relatives of dinosaurs.

Comment: Similar but not the same. Aquatic crocodiles that moved onto land all show a 4 legged posture. There was no evidence of any move towards a two legged posture in those particular fossils . As far as I am aware dinosaurs on the other hand adopted a 2 legged posture at the very beginning of their evolutionary history.